# Exchange values between userform and main module in vba

Tags: excel, vba, module, userform

I've been working on this problem for hours now, so I'll really appreciate any answers.

I have a userform with three buttons and I like them to pass a value, so I can use that value in my main module and depending on the value, run a specific code.
I searched everywhere but they all pass values from textboxs

Here is my userform code:

```
private sub cancelButton_Click()
    response = 1
    UserForm1.Hide
End Sub

private Sub SutunButton_Click()
    response = 2
    UserForm1.Hide
End Sub

private Sub TirButton_Click()
    response = 3
    UserForm1.Hide
End Sub
```

and this is my main module:

```
public response as integer
sub example()
.
.
.
userform1.show
if response=1 then
msgbox "1"
elseif response = 2 then
msgbox "2"
elseif response = 3 then
msgbox "3"
end if
.
.
.
end sub
```

Of course I put `msgbox` to make my code simple.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1):

Remove the global.  To the module add:

```
Public Sub process(form As UserForm1, response As Integer)
    form.Hide

    Select Case response
        Case 1: MsgBox 1
        Case 2: MsgBox 2
        Case 3: MsgBox 3
    End Select
End Sub
```

Change the events to:

```
private Sub SutunButton_Click()
    process Me, 2
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks for the reply :)
but it seems that "process" is not recognized as a function or a sub. what's the problem?!